# OutOfMemoryError while showing phone cotacts

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-contacts

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3576)

at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3531)

at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3380)
```

In my Application I show the user all the phone contacts and ask the user to select few or all
the contacts to be used in our application. I show the user all the contacts at once. No lazy loading or something like this. It working fine if i show them up to 1000 contacts but if there are more than 5000 contacts in the phone and if I try to show them in one go. I am getting OutOfMemoryError. How to solve this issue.

Comment: post your relevant code/logcat for others to help you.

Comment: Implement paging to load data in list view form contact provider.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: if u use viewholder in listview

Comment: you can refer this link http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through **ListView** Tutorial and implement a ListView using **ViewHolder model** to recycle the memory whenever it need. It is expected to give the OutOfMemoryError if you add all the element at once . Where as in listView  you can see all the contact by scrolling up and down, only the few content based on size of device will be allocated the memory at at a time

Comment: thanks for help...although i am able to show 3000 contacts at once but for 4000 contacts i am getting OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: it is expected to happen. Now ur device is  showing 3000 contact but if u run on low-end device then it will load not more then 500 contact so better u Implement ListView. Otherwise u'll face several device specific issue.

Comment: i am implementing list view with a low end device and its showing 3000 contacts without any problem but its crashing with OutOfMemoryError for 4000 contacts..

Comment: @sabyaHave u implemented using viewHolder model

Comment: no, i am implementing simply listview with baseadapter.. here iz the code of [baseadpater](http://pastie.org/8293575) and [my listview dialog](http://pastie.org/8293579)

Comment: @sabyaI explicitly said in my ans to implement ViewHolder model in ur code ,which u re not doing(i checked ur code).so its my last suggestion is to Implement paging(ViewHolder) to load data in list view form contact provider

Comment: check out this for ViewHolder
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145602/how-to-implement-a-view-holder
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145602/how-to-implement-a-view-holder

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and view it with a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

The `ListView` will recycle the memory when it needs to.

Comment: would not it show again OutOfMemoryError if i try to show 5000 contacts in list view in one go??

Comment: We don't know because we don't have enough info. But it is the first step. You may have to do more, such as only keep the selected items in memory.